# How to get Log after Deploying Talend job on SpagoBI

Tags: spagobi

After Deploying my Talend job in SpagoBi ,If any Error Occur After Exection of job through SpagoBi How i get to Know where and what Error Occur.
I have seen Log file in SpagoBi But its not Specific,its not giving me whole information.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to check this is to examine the logs/SpagoBITalendEngine.log file.